# Web.config redirect

Tags: html, iis, web-config, redirect

I've recently redesigned our website and moved it to a new domain. I need to do some redirects and I'm having some problems getting it to work properly.

I have over 200 pages I need to redirect and I'd prefer to do it in one rule rather than 200.

Here's an example of one I need to redirect:

> www.OldSite.net/store/index.php/**store**_location

redirected to:

> www.NewSite.com/store/page.aspx?code=**store**

The bolded part of the old `.net url` is what I'm trying to query and use in the new `.com url`. I'm having difficulty figuring out how to use wildcards, `{R:x}s` and `{C:x}s` in the web.config.

I've been able to get a single redirect to work by using a rule with:

> conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false"
>
> add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}"
>   pattern="www.OldSite.net/store/index.php/store_location" /
>
> /conditions
>
> action type="Redirect"
>   url="https://www.NewSite.com/store/page.aspx?code=store"
>   redirectType="Permanent"/*

But I was hoping there was an easier way to do it all with one rule instead of 200+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through a bunch of trial and error (mostly error :D) I was finally able to get one rule to do all the redirecting for me. In case this helps anyone else, here is the rule I used:

> rule name="redirect rule" stopProcessing="true"
>
> match url="(.*)/(.*)_" /
>
> conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" >trackAllCaptures="false"
>
> add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="www.OldSite.net/store/index.php/" /
>
> /conditions
>
> action type="Redirect" url="https://www.NewSite.com/store/page.aspx?code={R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" /
>
> /rule